# "'int' object is not callable" using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Getting the error `'int' object is not callable` when trying to execute the code:

```
sheetNames = wb.get_sheet_names()
activeSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
min = activeSheet.min_row() + 1
max = activeSheet.max_row()
```

I don't know what is causing this, considering neither the min declaration (with the addition operation) and the max function (without any operation) are working, both are giving that same error. The documentation says that `.min_row()` and `.max_row()` are both ints, so I'm not sure why I wouldn't be able to save them to otherwise undeclared variables. Any advice?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're shadowing the built in `min` and `max` functions. Also, I'm guessing `min_row` and `max_row` are properties, not functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither min_row nor max_row are functions, you don't need to call them:

```
min = activeSheet.min_row + 1
max = activeSheet.max_row
```